# Should [estimating] and [estimation] be synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Should [estimating](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimating) (161 questions) and [estimation](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimation) (6 questions) tags be merged / made synonyms? I believe they share the same meaning and only one of them should be used. Even though [estimation](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimation) has less number of posts but in my opinion its a better worded tag for PM.SE site.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a difference in the definitions, so I agree that they should be made synonyms. I also agree that [estimating](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimating) should point back to [estimation](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimation) as the canonical name for the activity. Additionally, I'd suggest adding [estimates](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimates) as another synonym.

Comment: Agree - just applied it: https://pm.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all